# set form target and submit it in safari

Tags: javascript, forms, safari

Need some help. This javascript code should set the target of the form and submit it. doesn't work in safari 5.0.2 ... why???

```
<html>
    <body>You will be redirected to PayPal in a few seconds.
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/webscr" id="paypal_standard_checkout" name="paypal_standard_checkout" method="POST">
     <input id="business" name="business" value="test@testxyz.com" type="hidden"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("paypal_standard_checkout").setAttribute("target","payment"); 
     document.getElementById("paypal_standard_checkout").submit();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: which part doesn't work? setting the target? submitting the form? or both? (and Safari on Win or Mac?)

Comment: Yeah, this is way too unclear. Also, is the target an existing window?

Comment: setting the target works, but submitting, nothing happens, no error, nothing,  safari mac, target window is not existing 

http://mikaella.org/submittest.html

Comment: Have you tried to do it on window.onload?

Comment: BTW without setting the target, it works ->>< ????

Comment: @epascarello, yes, and it works when manually triggered, but i need it  automatically, and i can't just set the target in the form tag

Comment: You are effectively using javascript to open a new window without user interaction.. this should be most likely getting caught by popup blockers..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't work for me in Safari 5.0.1 then i unchecked 'Block Pop-Up Windows' from the edit menu and then it was working fine :)

Code seems to be working fine, just being blocked.

Comment: :) thanks a lot , did't think of it, thought there should be a notification for this case  .. maybe i should go to sleep